# Docker for Windows - Settings to Cisco AnyConnect allow share driver

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, cisco-anyconnect

VPN is blocking my attempt to allows Docker for Windows to share C: on windows 10 machine.

Works fine when im out off VPN. When its on I get

> A firewall is blocking file Sharing between Windows and the
>   containers. See documentation for more info.

The documentation says

> You do not need to open port 445 on any other network. By default,
>   allow connections to 10.0.75.1 port 445 (the Windows host) from
>   10.0.75.2 (the virtual machine).

I am "googled out" on trying to find how to do that - can someone advise?

I am usign docker 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513), Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.12020 and Symatec Endpoint 14.

When im on office and use cable everything works, but on home when I connect VPN I can't share drive with docker. Due to company policies, I am required to use this VPN client.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 6):

I haven't spent enough time to get this working on my specific environment, but this looks promising: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/360

They suggest changing the subnet address in Docker to something the VPN doesn't use.

**Edit:** If that doesn't work and your employer allows you to use another VPN client, I've had success using OpenConnect in place of Cisco AnyConnect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this but I did not succeed. If you have another tip I thank you.

Comment: I'll keep looking.  I'm in a similar boat.  I'm not sure if my company has a policy against using OpenConnect, so I'm doing that for now, but I'd like to get Docker and AnyConnect to play nicely.

Comment: Were you able to configure OpenConnect to work on the VPN?

Comment: I didn't have to do any configuration.  I just used OpenConnect to sign in to my company's VPN and everything worked fine.

Comment: This answer is correct, but to make it clearer what the fix is I created a blog post with pictures: https://lukerogers.com/2018/09/22/docker-file-sharing-w-cisco-vpn/ 
The key is finding a non-secured route and using that range for Docker.